# Pastebin.com Post

Tags: javascript, post, pastebin

I'm trying to post a new Pastebin through a popup window in Javascript. The issues I'm getting is it is saying "Bad API request, invalid api_option"

Link that I'm using:
`http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php?api_dev_key=<KEY>&api_paste_name=T‌​ITLE&api_option=paste&api_paste_code=SOMETEXT`

It says to put api_option as paste. I've tried looking up other examples, but no luck yet. Has everyone ran into this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Are you, by any chance, required to POST the data rather than GETting it?

Also, it might not be the best idea ever to put your API key on the internet like this.

Comment: I'm sorry. Laptop was dying thought I deleted that... And I might not be able to... Could easily explain the lack of other answers.

Answer (score 3):

How are you submitting this request to Pastebin?  Is it via `POST` or `GET`?  My best guess is that you're sending a `GET` request and the API requires a `POST`.

Comment: Um. Well, I'm just literally opening the window.

`window.open('http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php?api_dev_key=&api_paste_name=TITLE&api_option=paste&api_paste_code='+escape(getSomethingIneed)); `

It seemed to work with PasteHTML.com... I'm just toying around I could be quite wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   let api = {
      option: "paste",
      user_key: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
      dev_key: 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
      paste_name: "MyTitle",
      paste_format: "JSON",
      paste_private: 0,
      paste_code: ""
};

  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', 'http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php', true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
  data['test'] = 'Yeah PasteBin!';
  dataString = 'api_option='+api.option+'&api_user_key='+api.user_key+'&api_dev_key='+api.dev_key+
'&api_paste_name='+api.paste_name+'&api_paste_format='+api.paste_format+
'&api_paste_private='+api.paste_private+'&api_paste_code='+data;
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.status == 200 && request.readyState == 4) {
        alert("URL to new pastebin file: " + request.responseText);
    }
}
  request.send(dataString);
```

The main issue with your code is put everything in your request URL, what is fine if it is a GET request. The URL of PasteBin: api/api_post.php demands a POST request (notice the name?), so you have to send it in the body like I've shown you above.